# In ASP.net Identity, how do you redirect a user to a specific url after login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I'm use the ASP.Net identity 2.0 package for my application. After a user successfully logs in, I want to redirect them to a specific URL on the site. Presently, after successful authorization, it sends them back to the default index page.

I *think* it's somewhere in this section of AccountController.cs:

```
 //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doen't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                if (user.LoginStage <= 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("EnableGoogleAuthenticator", "Manage");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);` to `return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");`

But this means you are ignoring the `returnUrl`.

Answer (score 1):

I use a `Response.Redirect("~/SomePage", false);`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well, it's what I use in my app.

Comment: So, the question is a bit unclear (there is no clear problem statement), but it appears that the individual is trying to figure out where *specifically in this code* the redirect happens. This answer seems like it makes more sense as a comment. I've voted to close though.

Comment: Somehow that was the only thing that worked for me with .net core 2.2 Authentication without Identity. I scaffolded the Identity package and reworked it so that I could drop the Identity package. The usual **LocalRedirect()** just kept throwing 500 server error. Changing it to **Response.Redirect** just made it work. Thanks!